# How to assign shortcut key to a macro in PowerPoint 2007?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

How to assign a shortcut key to my macro? Is there any way to directly assign it through VBA code?

Answer (score 0):

There's an SDK available for this commercial software from Chirag Dalal
http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr.html

The SDK is here:
http://officeone.mvps.org/ppsctmgr/ppsctmgr_sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

This is also my problem today and buying an additional software just for this shortcut should not be reasonable. I found out that coding this in Autohotkey can actually work. This is a sample one that only need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and you can already run your macro. The prerequisite of course , you should have your macro in the custom tool bar button as addins.

```
LCtrl & r::
Send Raw{Alt}
SendRaw x
SendRaw y
Send Raw{Alt}
SendRaw h
Send Raw{Alt}
Goto, Exit
```

Hope this should help some guys who might have similar problems in the future.